# Merging two almost similar texts

Tags: xml, perl, diff, string-comparison

I have got the following tricky problem:

I have two basically identical texts, one of them xml-tagged, the other not.

The spelling in the text that contains xml-tags has been normalized - which I don't want. That's why I am looking for a method to merge the two texts: I have to substitute the xml-text with the very similar but not identical plain text keeping the xml-structure.

Does anybody know if that is possible? Is there a way to solve the problem in Perl?

Thank you very much!

Alex

---

**Example**

Normalized XML:

```
<div2>
<head>Title</head>
<p>Here is some normalized sample text.</p>
<p>The orthograph has been changed.</p>
</div2>
```

From original plain text:

> Titel
>
> Here is some normalised sample texte.
>
> The ortographe has been changed.

I'd like to have an output like this:

```
<div2>
<head>Title</head>
<p>Here is some normalised sample texte.</p>
<p>The ortographe has been changed.</p>
</div2>
```

Comment: Would it be possible that you provide a minimal sample of what you want to do ? Or should we try and imagine your input and output ourselves?

Comment: You can try to attach words based on [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_distance) or similar measure.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not provide a minimal sample.

Comment: Hope the one above will do ...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I'd suggest using [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aDiff) for this.  Basically, if you took a character-by-character diff of your two texts, you should get something like this:

```xml
[+<div2>+]
[+<head>+]Tit[-e-]l[+e</head>+]
[+<p>+]Here is some normali[-s-][+z+]ed sample text[-e-].[+</p>+]
[+<p>+]The ort[+h+]ograph[-e-] has been changed.[+</p>+]
[+</div2>+]
```

You'll notice that there are some XML tag insertions interspersed with textual changes.  Now, if you simply took the tags from the `+` version and the text from the `-` version, you should get the combined text you want.

For best effect, I'd recommend using a smart tokenizer that treats XML tags as single tokens, so that e.g. `<p>foo</p>` would be split into `<p>`, `f`, `o`, `o`, `</p>`.  That not only makes the diff faster and parsing the output easier, but also avoids the risk that the diff algorithm might split a tag into several chunks or confuse it with text.

Here's some sample code:

```perl
sub merge_tags {
    my ($orig, $tagged) = @_;

    # tokenize strings into tags and chars (could use a real XML parser here)
    $_ = [/\G(<(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>|.)/sg] for $orig, $tagged;

    require Algorithm::Diff;
    my $diff = Algorithm::Diff->new( $orig, $tagged );

    my @output;
    while ($diff->Next) {
        if ($diff->Diff) {
            my @text = grep !/^<.*>$/s, $diff->Items(1);
            my @tags = grep  /^<.*>$/s, $diff->Items(2);
            # kluge: output opening tags first
            push @output, shift @tags while @tags and $tags[0] !~ /^<\//;
            push @output, @text, @tags;
        }
        else {
            push @output, $diff->Same;
        }
    }
    return join "", @output;
}
```

I'm sure this code could be improved (for example, it could be smarter about tag nesting), but at least it works for your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always the same number of words and the same order - you can just replace the words one by one.

Comment: of course, this might work. Two problems remain, though (and I apologize for my technical ignorance ... I'm working on it): 1) I would have to ignore the xml-tags while replacing the words ... a skill I haven't acquired so far; 2) I cannot be entirely sure if the word order is exactly the same. There might be some mistakes (= differences) and I don't want to ruin the text without even noticing it. So a check routine would be nice. I'd better have a look at how insert a thing like this.